# Someone changed my screen mode in the terminal and now I can't scroll up

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Very noob question - I'm new to coding/ubuntu/bash. My supervisor ran some commands in my terminal for some data processing, and now my scroll bar is disabled and I cannot move upwards or scroll. I need to go back up the screen so I can save the scripts for future use. He said something about copy mode or edit mode. I have tried:
Ctrl A
Ctrl Q
(a bunch of other Ctrl commands)
enabling quick edit mode
increasing screen buffer height

It has happened before and he quickly got out of it by using a Ctrl command - seems to be a pretty normal function but I cant find the correct answer anywhere online.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just ask your supervisor how to fix it? Ask them what to do instead of letting them do it, and that way you will remember.

Comment: When you say "screen mode" are you referring to the GNU `screen` terminal multiplexer's [copy mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Copy.html) ?

Comment: Is this all in a terminal? If so and you want to see the commands you’ve typed, arrow-up (as many times as you need) or enter ‘history’ and you’ll see the commands you’ve typed.